# how to generate EXE file?

Tags: file, binary, exe

I have been developing a compiler and I want it to generate the output file as exe .
How can we do that?

Is there any way to do that without using any assembly language ?

Comment: Um, no. I suggest you study a programming language and design book before you even think of doing something as complicated as building a compiler.

Comment: so does it mean turbo C also uses assembly for that ?

Comment: All compilers work by translating your code into assembly language, and then using the system assembler to convert that into executable code. They've been doing it this way for ages.

Comment: which means i have no other choice than going the assembly way...?

Comment: No other choice. If you want an .exe, you need to know assembly. That' stat.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`I have been developing a compiler and I want it to generate the output file as exe . How can we do that?`

Pretty complicated topic. Realistically, if you're trying to generate a true executable file, you'll need to read up on several different areas (the assembly language of the target architecture, the target OS, linking / loading, etc.)

`Is there any way to do that without using any assembly language ?`

You can do all of your code gen in a high level language. But you should still understand the assembly that you're trying to generate :)